# Convert a generic extended class(from LinkedList) to JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, linked-list, gson, sharedpreferences

My goal is to save and read the object of a class into SharedPreferences.

The class that I need to save in SharedPreferences is a custom generic class 'LimitedQueue' which extends 'LinkedList' class: I wrote the 'LimitedQueue' because I need a fixed size Queue class that removes the oldest element when I add a new element.

```
public class LimitedQueue<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
  @SerializedName("limit")
  private int limit;

  public LimitedQueue(int limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(E o) {
    super.add(o);
    while (size() > limit) { super.remove(); }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Saving is fine but to read the above class from SharedPreferences I get an error using the following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mAppSettingSharedPreferences.getString(
        "myListObject", "");
Type type = new TypeToken<LimitedQueue<Integer>>(){}.getType();
LimitedQueue<Integer> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

I get the error:

```
java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to myapp.com.LimitedQueue
```

How can I deserialize my class which extends LinkedList using gson?

Comment: Could you simply `toString` the list and save it as a String? Why bother with Gson?

Comment: Then is not possible to easily load it. Is it?

Comment: It might not preserve the generic type, but if you delimit the data, then sure. Take `"1,2,3"`,  split on the commas, loop over the parts, add back to a new list.

Comment: Yes that is another approach and will work, but I wanna know what is wrong with this gson.fromJson() second argument. I know something is missing in my class definition. I added @SerializedName("limit") but still to no avail.

Comment: Gson is trying to cast your subclass of LinkedList to your LimitedQueue class. Don't know why, but yeah, adding that annotation shouldn't fix it

Comment: I gave up the idea of using Gson. I am currently using the toString solution offered  by cricket_007.